# Data Science Association?

Tags: knowledge-base

Have you heard of the "Data Science Association"? 

URL: http://www.datascienceassn.org/

Do you expect it to become a professional body like the Actuaries Institute?

If yes, then why?

If no, then why not and do you see anyone else becoming the professional body?

Lastly, is this question "on-topic" ?

Comment: It looks like there are no prerequisites for membership, without which I see no reason why membership should carry any meaning. Membership is supposed to be a "Valuable credential to signal to clients and employers", but this will only be true if there is some sort of qualification requirement/entrance exam and also some industry experience requirements. With a free for all membership, being a member doesn't distinguish you from a non-member.

Comment: @AsheeshR, yes this question is a matter of opinion but I think that the community can really benefit from it. How do we proceed?

Comment: @power Please take a look at http://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. If you still disagree, please raise the issue on [meta].

Comment: @AsheeshR Okay, I will re-word the question shortly.